# iterating over files in loop and skipping data and reading after that gives error

Tags: python, file-io, iterator

I have multiple directories and many files in each directory and I want to iterate through each of them. I also want to read only the `5th` line of each file, hence ignore the first four lines. When I run the script without ignoring trying to ignore first `4` lines it runs fine. Here is the code:

```
import os

#find the present working directory
pwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#find all the folders in the present working directory.
dirs = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(f)]

for directory in dirs:
        os.chdir(os.path.join(pwd, directory));
        chd_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        files = [ fl for fl in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(fl) ]
        print files
        for f in files:
                f_obj = open(os.path.join(chd_dir, f), 'r')
                for i in xrange(0,4): #ignore the first 4 lines
                        f_obj.next()
                s=f_obj.readline()
                print s
                f_obj.close()
```

This script gives the following error:
`ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data`

I do not understand why python thinks that I would lose some data and I would also like to know the work around that fixes it and why does it fixes it.

Comment: have you looked into using `os.walk`? This will do what you're trying to do more simply, and may eliminate this error.

Comment: @COpython: `os.walk` is excellent, but won't eliminate the error.

Comment: @COpython Yeah I know I will change that. Actually it was my previous question on SO, I haven't changed it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reed the 5th line with the `.next()` method:

```
s = f_obj.next()
```

The file iteration method uses buffering to remain efficient, and that buffer is not shared with the `.readline()` and other read methods of the file object. Thus, you'll miss out on data when mixing iteration and read methods.

From the [`.next()` method documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects):

> In order to make a for loop the most efficient way of looping over the lines of a file (a very common operation), the `next()` method uses a hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead buffer, combining `next()` with other file methods (like `readline()`) does not work right.

You could replace the `.next()` calls with `.readline()` calls as well, just be consistent and use one or the other.

Comment: I also need to know why my method is producing error. Anyways thanks for the fix.